# Where can I find the stocks online/offline data?

Tags: stocks, cryptocurrency, historical-data, online-data-source, market-data

I have 3 questions:

1- Where can I find the historical data of stocks and cryptocurrencies, etc. as `.CSV` file for free?

2- Where can I get online data of stocks/cryptocurrencies for free? I mean a free API that I can get data from it in real-time and use it in my application/software.

3- Is web scraping/crawling to grab online/offline such data from the websites illegal in the US?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo Finance offers free historical stock data but they sometimes have issues with reliability.  You can also google for other sources.